# replication normal mysql to cluster

Tags: mysql, scalability, cluster-computing, database-replication, multi-master-replication

Surprisingly I can't find anything on the internet which speaks to this.  We currently have a master slave slave mysql set up.  We are considering making a move to mysql cluster, for scalability reasons.  It would be really nice if we could make the cluster a slave of the current master and run a dev environment off the cluster for now.  Even better would be if we could do a master master relationship between the current master and the cluster.

Our concern is that our data has to be kept very current, so not being able to do this replication would mean downtime.  If this replication is not possible, what is the smoothest possible way to make the transition.  We're currently running mariaDB.

Comment: Switching out your MySQL slave to a MySQL cluster is doable. The master-master thing will be only manageable if your application already has separate *write* and *read* logic. Without that, I wouldn't even think about that. (Also joins *are* slow, no joke.) Describing the whole process is too complex, but I recommend you read the [reference manual's section on this topic](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-cluster.html). There is also [a good article on a scenario which could be helpful to you](http://johanandersson.blogspot.hu/2009/05/ha-mysql-write-scaling-using-cluster-to.html).